# Import spreadsheet in a CQRS event sourced system

Tags: import, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a system that uses CQRS + ES.  I need to import aggregates from spreadsheets and was wondering if anyone had any ideas about the best way to go about it.

My initial thought was to go through the spreadsheet and create X amount of "CreateNewAggregateCommand" type commands.  I could then run those commands and they would act as if a user had created a single command using the UI.  Does this seem correct or is there a better way?

What if it's important that if one row in the spreadsheet fails to import then the whole file needs to be rejected.  In an eventually consistent system, if one row in the import failed how would you deal with consistency?  Would you issue some sort of compensating command?

Answer (score 2):

In event sourced systems import or mass updates actions are usually implemented as special command handlers and raising special events, like ImportFromSpreadsheet/ImportedFromSpreadsheet. This allows easier tracking of the behaviour, so you clearly know that this particular row was imported, not manually created. You can use regular events in case you also save commands in your event store for audit purposes.

According the row import failure, in given conditions I would heavily avoid importing rows and expecting an error somewhere in the middle. It would be much easier if you pre-validate your completely spreadsheet to ensure it will import. I know that it might be hard but you can have a field in your command that will indicate that you are doing the validation so it should not raise any events so you can keep logic the same for validation and actual import.

Answer (score 0):

We need to be pragmatic here, if you need to import thousand of entries you won't be doing it one by one. Here is what you should do, using a known pattern [Claim Check](http://www.eaipatterns.com/StoreInLibrary.html)

Push your file to your server, upload it to a FTP location or something like that and then create a simple command to initiate the importing process. Use a GUID as the file name, and in your command add that file name, the handler should then verify that the file exists and start processing the file.

Hope this helps.